# How do I make this schema?

Tags: sql, schema

I have a table called tbl_AllowedIpRange with the columns:

> ipFrom | ipTo

I have two tables that represent entities that can have allowed IP's assigned to them. tbl_Category and tbl_MediaItem.

What im wondering is how I link the two tables to reuse the tbl_AllowedIpRange table and keep things in the 3nf?

I was thinking that I could put two columns in the tbl_AllowedIpRange table?

> CategoryId | MediaItemId | ipFrom | ipTo

Then write a two methods to get the alloed ip for each table trying to get access to it.

> NOTE: I cant use one single column for the foreign key in the
>   tbl_AllowedIpRange because it will contain conflicting keys from the
>   other tables as it will point to their primary keys....

Is there an easier way using a link table?

Comment: Will the table `tbl_Category` and `tbl_MediaItem` be part of the _same_ ip range, or different ranges?

Comment: different..they need to have seperate ranges...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table `tbl_AllowedIpRange` should have an autoincrement `PRIMARY KEY`, which you can use to reference in other tables. So...

#### 1. Add a referenceable primary key to the table `tbl_AllowedIpRange`

```
range_id | ipFrom | ipTo
```

#### 2. Create a table to hold the relationship between `tbl_Category` and `tbl_AllowedIpRange`

Suggested table name: `Category_AllowedIpRanges`

```
category_id | range_id
```

#### 3. Create a table to hold the relationship between `tbl_MediaItem` and `tbl_AllowedIpRange`

Suggested table name: `MediaItem_AllowedIpRanges`

```
mediaitem_id | range_id
```